# jquery draggable does not worked

Tags: jquery

I am doing the jquery draggable it work fine in the initial case but it does not work when a new same div is created with jswhat is the actual problem with my code please help me 
http://galtech.org/testing/drag_new.php
Drag me old worked fine
But new draggable div is created with New element (red anchor in bottom )
it does not have draggable property

```
 <script>
  function shw()
  {
    $("#name").html('<div id="draggable">Drag me new</div>');
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {

     $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ cursor: 'move', containment: '#name', opacity: 0.35 }); 
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body >
  <div id="name" style="background:#9999FF; height:500px; width:500px;"> 
<div id="draggable">Drag me old</div>
</div>
<a onClick="shw();" style="background-color:#FF0000; cursor:pointer;">New element</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-initialize the draggable. Make what's in document.ready a function and call it after you add the new draggable

Answer (score 0):

You're adding an element to the dom that wasn't present at its initialization.

If you want to use a function on a element created in the future, you can use the `live` function from jQuery

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

**Edit** : Since `live` can't work here, there's an plugin I used once that work here :
[liveQuery](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/demos)

[Here's the jsFiddle with livequery that work with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/V4BSb/)

Comment: You can't use `.live()` like that; it only works for events that bubble up the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <script>
>
> function shw()   {
>    $("#name").html('<div id="draggable">Drag me new</div>');
> }
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> $( "#draggable" ).draggable({ cursor: 'move', containment:
> ```
>
> '#name',opacity: 0.35});
>
> ```
> });
>
> </script>
> ```

Initialize draggable after adding new elements

```
function shw()   {
   $("#name").html('<div id="draggable">Drag me new</div>')
.find('#draggable').draggable({ cursor: 'move', containment:'#name',opacity: 0.35});
}

$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ cursor: 'move', containment:'#name',opacity: 0.35});

});
```

Comment: pleae help me to fix this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967315/jquery-draggble-has-a-problem-on-dragging